# Pycharm: show x/y coordinates with matplotlib automatically

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

If I plot with ipython, I automatically see the x/y coordinates when I move with the mouse over the canvas (see bottom right in screenshot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_random = np.random.random(5)
plt.plot(my_random)
plt.show()
```

**How can the same achieved with Pycharm** (my plots appear in the SciView toolwindow)?

If not: is there perhaps an easy workaround for it? (and do I have more possibilities if the plot does not appear in the SciView toolwindow?)

[image: x/y coordinates depicted at bottom right]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/widgets/cursor.html ??

Comment: unfortunately, this does not seem to help

Comment: Not sure what the "SciView toolwindow" is, but probably it shows the plots as png images, which do not have any interactivity, so no coordinates can be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `TkAgg` it works:

```
import matplotlib   
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_random = np.random.random(5)
plt.plot(my_random)
plt.show()
```